# How to convert string to Unix Epoch time in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, unix-timestamp, epoch

I would like to convert strings with format like `2018-10-15T06:42:17.055476324Z` to Unix Epoch format. So it will just be an integer of seconds. How to do this in Python3?

Comment: I'm sure that a quick search on any search engine will point you in the right direction. Please make an effort before posting a question.

Comment: Python comes with batteries included: see the `datetime` and `time` modules.